# View between menu items in toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to take view in menu items of toolbar?

[image]

I want view like shown in yellow color between two menu items of toolbar.

Comment: it could be possible but you have to ignore the click event of this view. In short you have a divider view but in reality it is a `menuitem` but on clicking the button you have to ignore its click behavious

Comment: take 3 menu items with property `app:showAsAction="always"` and 2nd menu item **drawable** source will be divider line image.

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a divider line view in xml file to show a divider line.

**dividerLine.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<View
android:layout_width="1dp"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize" 
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/> 
 </LinearLayout>
```

and set `actionLayout` to an item in menu xml to show divider line

**activity_menu.xml**

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:id="@+id/your_icon1"
      android:icon="@drawable/image1"
      android:title="@string/text1"
      app:showAsAction="always"
      />

<item android:id="@+id/icon2TricktoShowDividerLine"
     android:actionLayout="@layout/dividerLine" 
     app:showAsAction="always"
     android:title="@string/text2" />

<item android:id="@+id/your_icon3"
      android:icon="@drawable/icon"
      android:title="@string/text3"
      app:showAsAction="always" />
 </menu>
```

**android:actionLayout="@layout/dividerLine"**  shows divider line between menu items. Hope this helps you.

**Updated**

I am getting this type of view from my above code :

[image]

Comment: Have you tried it because it is not visible in toolbar

Comment: @Salmankhan yes i have tried it working fine for me ,try to change background color of a view in `dividerLine.xml` to make it visible

Comment: I tried it already with different colors, but not visible at all. Show me your demo or image having this toolbar with divider view.

Comment: @Salmankhan check out the screenshot i have updated in my answer

Comment: Need to take app:actionLayout instead of android:actionLayout. But anyways thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the `custom layout` for `menuItem` uing `actionLayout` and then in `oncreateOptionsMenue` get the menuItem view and change your image view icon to vertical drawable

**layout_actionitem.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/actionItemImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Your menu xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_save"
        android:icon="@drawable/exit"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/layout_actionitem"
        android:title=""/>
</menu>
```

**onCreateOptionsMenu**

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        LinearLayout actionItemLayout = (LinearLayout) menu.findItem(R.id.item_save).getActionView();
        ImageView iv = (ImageView)actionItemLayout.findViewById(R.id.actionItemImage);
        iv.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_save));
}
```

Hope this helps.